# Google analytics experiment over different languages in url

Tags: google-analytics

I got a website where I'm currently tracking the clicks to my signup page from my login page.
Now I'm facing the problem that my url contains the users language and that I want to track these targets, ignoring the user's language setting.

example of my urls:

```
Login:
www.mywebsite.com/en/signin
www.mywebsite.com/nl/signin

Signup:
www.mywebsite.com/en/signup
www.mywebsite.com/nl/signup
```

Is this possible to track or should I create an experiment per language? (What I would find very cumbersome)

Comment: Sorry, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. You can implement one Experiment that is tracking multiple languages. For instance you could use the Content Experiments JavaScript API to track, [read Google's client-side experiments guide here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side).

Summary:

1. Load `<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=EXPERIMENT_ID"></script>` on each page to be part of the experiment (www.mywebsite.com/[lang]/signin)
2. `var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();`
3. `cxApi.setChosenVariation(chosenVariation);` (this writes the __utmx and __utmxx cookies)
4. After the cookies are set you can use your tracking API (e.g. `ga('send', 'pageview');` )
5. Now Google is tracking all pages from 1. in your experiment with EXPERIMENT_ID

You'll [find the xcApi reference here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/experiments#cxjs)

I hope this helps!